# VB.net - Detecting if someone clicks "f5"

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a Visual Basic program, and I want it if you click F5, the program's current form refreshes.

I mostly just need to code to detect if someone clicks the key "F5"

I've tried below, but any keys refresh it then.

```
Private Sub LoginBox_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then
       Me.Close
       Loginbox.show
    Else
       'Do nothing
      End If
End Sub
```

EDIT: Both John Koerner and Nadeem_MK have the right answers.

I used Nadeem's for the sub and then used the Closing method from John Koerner.

I can only have one be the answer... But thanks anyways! Last time didn't go far.

I asked this before... but "somehow" people didn't understand this very basic question.

Comment: Is the LoginBox you're coding is the form name or a control on your form?

Comment: Is there something in your FormClosing Sub?

Comment: Yeah, give us more detail. There is nothing in your code example shows a form refresh on "any" key.

Comment: Do you want a given control (e.g., the form) being selected or you expect F5 being tracked in any case (even when the program is minimised?). Because note that your code is only triggered when the form is selected.

Comment: Loginbox is the form name. I thought "e.Keycode = Keys.F5" would work, but it just registers all the keys

Comment: Nothing in formclosing sub

Comment: PS: regarding "I asked this before... but "somehow" people didn't understand this very basic question.", perhaps you should make an effort to make yourself clear; mainly by bearing in mind that there might be many more alternatives than what you think (refer to my comment above) and that the most common source of errors/problems are misunderstandings and not having a clear-enough picture.

Comment: @varocarbas How could I be more simpler then "I need it so if someone clicks "F5" it closes and reopens the form I mostly need the key code."? Then someone just closes the question.

Comment: I have read your previous question. The problem was that you weren't asking anything, neither explaining the problems you found. This time you weren't much clearer but, at least, you said that you want to "detect if someone clicks the key "F5" and what is wrong with your code "I've tried below, but any keys refresh it then."; neither of these issues were clear in your previous question. Also even in this one there are quite a few unclear bits (what I asked for example). Better take your time to write a clear question and answer anyone requesting clarifications.

Comment: PS: you don't need to explain your decision process in your question, you can be as grateful as you wish in each specific answer. PPS: if you are not interested in your previous question anymore, just delete it. And better bear in mind what all this is about (i.e., helping you but also any other future reader with an equivalent problem) and that people here only intends to help (if someone requests something that you can do without any effort, just do it) and you will surely enjoy SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just tested it in VS2008 and it seem to me that the Form event of KeyPress, Keydown and KeyUp do not trigger on button press.
 To do so, you need to put the `Me.KeyPreview = True` on FormLoad() and then proceed;

```
Private Sub Form_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Form.KeyDown

        If e.KeyData = Keys.F5 Then
            Me.Refresh()
        End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Me.Refresh doesn't work. Other then that it works fine. I just need it to somehow open on refresh only

Comment: Yeah it won't detect until you put `Me.KeyPreview = True` in your FormLoad() event, that is on loading the form. I just tested it and it works fine for me

Comment: I combined your answer with the one above. It helped it work. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yeah, that's what I meant in the 1st part but didn't write the code. You can mark it as answer if it worked for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

In order to catch certain key presses, you need to set KeyPreview = True.  Also, if this is the only form open in your app and you close it, then your app will close completely when you call Me.Close(), so you need to show the new form before you close the old one.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.KeyPreview = True
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.F5 Then
        Me.Hide()
        Dim f As New Form1
        f.ShowDialog()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I combined your answer with the one below. It helped it work. Thanks!